# where are the infos from 'SHOW CREATE TABLE' coming from? It's not INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Tags: mysql, mariadb, table, information-schema, metadata

Quote from [MariaDB 10.2 CHECK and DEFAULT clauses:](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/07/29/mariadb-10-2-check-and-default-clauses/)

> Another limitation is that CHECK metadata are not accessible via the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA. The only way to find out if a table has CHECK
>   clauses is parsing the output of SHOW CREATE TABLE.

I also found [in MariaDB KB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/show-create-table/)

> **Note that SHOW CREATE TABLE is not meant to provide metadata about a
>   table**. It provides information about how the table was declared, but
>   the real table structure could differ a bit. For example, if an index
>   has been declared as HASH, the CREATE TABLE statement returned by SHOW
>   CREATE TABLE will declare that index as HASH; however, it is possible
>   that the index is in fact a BTREE, because the storage engine does not
>   support HASH.

So from where does `SHOW CREATE TABLE` collect its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever since long, long, ago the info has come from the `.frm` file.  The I_S is relatively new.  In the future (5.8 maybe) the .frm will be replaced by an InnoDB-based table.

`CHECK` (and a few other things) are syntactically allowed but are *not* handled anywhere in the code.  (Another example is a `DESC` index.)  It could be that the .frm contains these strings, but there is no need for such *unused* information to be replicated in the I_S.